# C Compiler cannot create executables on SUA/Interix

Tags: c, compiler-errors, configure, interix, sua

Whenever I try to build an application with Interix's GCC on Windows, this is what happens:

```
/tmp/grep-2.5.4-src/build$ ../configure --build=x86_64-pc-interix6
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ../install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-interix6
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-interix6
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name...
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

To me it looks like the problem isn't with the compiler, but rather with the `configure` file.

How can I fix it so that it works with SUA?

config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GNU grep configure 2.5.4, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.61.  Invocation command line was

  $ ../configure --build=x86_64-pc-interix6

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = MehrdadVAIO
uname -m = genuineintel
uname -r = 6.1
uname -s = Interix
uname -v = 10.0.7063.0

/usr/bin/uname -p = Intel64_Family_6_Model_37_Stepping_2
/bin/uname -X     = 
System = Interix
Node = <<< my computer name >>>
Release = 6.1
Version = 10.0.7063.0
Machine = genuineintel
Processor = Intel64_Family_6_Model_37_Stepping_2
HostSystem = Windows
HostRelease = 6.1
HostVersion = SP1

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/X11/bin
PATH: /usr/local/vtcl
PATH: /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.1.2/bin
PATH: /opt/gcc64/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /opt/gcc.3.3/bin
PATH: /usr/contrib/bin
PATH: /usr/X11R6/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/contrib/win32/bin
PATH: /dev/fs/C/Windows/System32
PATH: /dev/fs/C/Windows/SUA/common
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/openwin/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1833: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:1889: result: /bin/install -c
configure:1900: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:1943: result: yes
configure:1972: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2011: result: ../install-sh -c -d
configure:2024: checking for gawk
configure:2040: found /usr/contrib/bin/gawk
configure:2051: result: gawk
configure:2062: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2083: result: yes
configure:2297: checking build system type
configure:2315: result: x86_64-pc-interix6
configure:2337: checking host system type
configure:2352: result: x86_64-pc-interix6
configure:2378: checking for gawk
configure:2405: result: gawk
configure:2464: checking for gcc
configure:2480: found /opt/gcc64/bin/gcc
configure:2491: result: gcc
configure:2729: checking for C compiler version
configure:2736: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 4.6.0 20110122 (experimental)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2739: $? = 0
configure:2746: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-pc-interix6
Configured with: ../../gcc/gcc/configure --build=x86_64-unkown-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-pc-interix6 --target=x86_64-pc-interix6 --prefix=/opt/gcc64 --with-local-prefix=/opt/gcc64/local --with-gnu-as --enable-threads=posix --disable-shared --disable-nls --disable-multilib --disable-libssp --disable-decimal-float --disable-fixed-point --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c --with-gmp-include=/interix/gcc/gnuxx/x86_64-pc-interix6/include --with-gmp-lib=/interix/gcc/gnuxx/x86_64-pc-interix6/lib --with-mpfr-include=/interix/gcc/gnuxx/x86_64-pc-interix6/include --with-mpfr-lib=/interix/gcc/gnuxx/x86_64-pc-interix6/lib --with-mpc-include=/interix/gcc/gnuxx/x86_64-pc-interix6/include --with-mpc-lib=/interix/gcc/gnuxx/x86_64-pc-interix6/lib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.0 20110122 (experimental) (GCC) 
configure:2749: $? = 0
configure:2756: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2759: $? = 1
configure:2782: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2809: gcc -D_ALL_SOURCE -D_ALL_SOURCE -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/ssl/include -I/usr/local/include/php  -lbind -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/ssl/lib conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
configure:2812: $? = 1
configure:2850: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU grep"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "grep"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.5.4"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU grep 2.5.4"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "bug-grep@gnu.org"
| #define GREP 1
| #define PACKAGE "grep"
| #define VERSION "2.5.4"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2856: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-interix6
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=-D_ALL_SOURCE
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value='-D_ALL_SOURCE -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/ssl/include -I/usr/local/include/php'
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=' -lbind -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/ssl/lib'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=x86_64-pc-interix6
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-interix6
ac_cv_path_install='/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /tmp/grep-2.5.4-src/missing --run aclocal-1.10'
ALLOCA=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} /tmp/grep-2.5.4-src/missing --run tar'
ANSI2KNR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /tmp/grep-2.5.4-src/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /tmp/grep-2.5.4-src/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /tmp/grep-2.5.4-src/missing --run automake-1.10'
AWK='gawk'
BUILD_INCLUDED_LIBINTL=''
CATALOGS=''
CATOBJEXT=''
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-D_ALL_SOURCE'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-D_ALL_SOURCE -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/ssl/include -I/usr/local/include/php'
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DATADIRNAME=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
GENCAT=''
GETCONF=''
GLIBC21=''
GMOFILES=''
GMSGFMT=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
INSTOBJEXT=''
INTLBISON=''
INTLLIBS=''
INTLOBJS=''
INTL_LIBTOOL_SUFFIX_PREFIX=''
LDFLAGS=' -lbind -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/ssl/lib'
LIBICONV=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /tmp/grep-2.5.4-src/missing --run makeinfo'
MKINSTALLDIRS=''
MSGFMT=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='grep'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='bug-grep@gnu.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='GNU grep'
PACKAGE_STRING='GNU grep 2.5.4'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='grep'
PACKAGE_VERSION='2.5.4'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
POFILES=''
POSUB=''
RANLIB=''
SEP=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
U=''
USE_INCLUDED_LIBINTL=''
USE_NLS=''
VERSION='2.5.4'
XGETTEXT=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=' -I$(srcdir)'
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-interix6'
build_alias='x86_64-pc-interix6'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='interix6'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-pc-interix6'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='interix6'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='$(SHELL) /tmp/grep-2.5.4-src/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(top_builddir)/../install-sh -c -d'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU grep"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "grep"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.5.4"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU grep 2.5.4"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "bug-grep@gnu.org"
#define GREP 1
#define PACKAGE "grep"
#define VERSION "2.5.4"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: It says "See config.log". What is there to be seen?

Comment: First, show us the output you get when you do it in another directory; the `No such file or directory` error is distracting.  Second, follow the advice and take a look at `config.log`; show us the relevant contents if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking for `cc1` as a compiler and can't find it, which is why it's failing.

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory.
```

So it's not that the compiler can't create executables, but that it can't find it. `gcc` invokes `cc1`. Check your system for it, or perhaps your `PATH`.

Comment: Shoot, I glanced at the log but totally missed that. :) I know what the path should be, but how do I do this properly so that it doesn't mess with Win32 stuff?

Comment: I just quickly looked around at the problem, which pointed out that you _shouldn't_ need `cc1` in your path, and suggested making sure `gcc` was installed properly. However, if you want the PATH to work during configuration, you can just do: `PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/cc1 ./configure`.

Comment: +1 Yeah I thought gcc installed fine, I don't know... but I just tried that, and now the log file says `/usr/lib/x86/safecrt0.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized`... I think it's because it's trying to compile it with x86 instead of x64 but I'm not sure why the installation seems so messed up. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mehrdad: If I were in your shoes, I'd first try compiling x64, to see if you get the same error. I assume you haven't done anything strange with the install, right?

Comment: Yeah I'm using the x64 compiler, but it's using the x86 libraries. Will try and see if I can get it working. As for doing anything strange -- I don't think so, but I've installed the [SUA tools](http://www.suacommunity.com/tool_warehouse.aspx)... it looked as though the install went fine, though.

Comment: So I'm seeing that `ld` is getting called with the command line `ld -stack 0x4000000,0x10000 /usr/lib/x86/safecrt0.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/gcc.3.3/lib -L/usr/lib/x86 -L/opt/gcc.3.3/.. /tmp/ccw4i4P9.o -lgcc -lcsafe -lpsxdll -lcsafe -lpsxdll -lgcc`... I can't figure out why it's looking at `/usr/lib/x86` though, since it's not even in my PATH (or anywhere else I can see). Ideas?

Comment: OOOOOH I got `configure` to work!!! It was because of the environmental variables `LIBRARY_PATH` (which was originally including `/usr/lib/x86` and which I set to `/usr/lib:/opt/gcc64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-interix6/4.6.0`) and I believe also `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (similar issue). Also, for anyone experiencing this, [this page](http://www.suacommunity.com/faqs.aspx#405) should be pretty helpful. :) Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Mehrdad: Wow, I've used `LIBRARY_PATH` before myself and for some reason it didn't come to mind... I thought it must have been something else! Anyway, glad you fixed it!